# Matplotlib numpy math functions

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to matplotlib, I would like to know whether what I am doing is correct.

The function is sin^2(x-2)e^-x^2, where the limits of x and y are [0,2] and [0,2] respectively.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return (np.sin(x-2)**2) *np.exp(np.power(-x,2))

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

#f(x) = sin2(x-2)e^-x2
y = f(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(x, y, 'r', label='sin2(x-2)e^-x2')
ax.set(xlim=(0,2), ylim=(0,2),
      xlabel='x values', ylabel='y values', title='f(x) = sin2(x-2)e^-x2')
```

I don't think my computation is correct. Is there anyway to improve this?

Comment: why do you think this is not correct?

Comment: i have a problem with the function. it has been noted by kwinkunks.

Comment: This is more of a typo / misplacement of the `-` sign. `np.exp(np.power(-x, 2))` should be `np.exp(-np.power(x, 2))`. It has to do with the order of operation. It's equivalent to `(-x)**2` compared to `-(x**2)`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney oh I see. I solved it by changing to -x**2. Well could've used -np.power().

Comment: That's correct. Order of operation is an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the parentheses in your function, leading you to square `-x`, instead of taking `-x**2`. Try this:

```
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x - 2)**2 * np.exp(-x**2)
```